# How to deselect all togglebuttons in a single screen?

Tags: java, javafx

I am a beginning to JavaFX and am writing an application for the first time. In a sequence of events, I've come across this problem.
I want to know how to deselect all the select toggle buttons in a screen without having to set each of them one-by-one. In C#, this can be done with the help of a foreach construct.

```
foreach (Control c in this.Controls) {
    if (C is Button) 
        //do stuff here
}
```

Is there an equivalent java code which I can use for the same?

Comment: *"in a single screen"* AFAIK you could add controls to controls so in C# this would only be applied to a single level of depth...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming all `ToggleButton`s are children of the same `Parent` `parent` this would be the JavaFX equivalent:

```
for (Node child : parent.getChildren()) {
    if (child instanceof ToggleButton) {
        ToggleButton button = (ToggleButton) child;
        ...
    }
}
```

Saving the buttons to a data structure like an array or `List` would be preferrable though, since it's independent of the scene structure and allows you to apply the changes to a subgroup of the `ToggleButton`s in the parent...

Comment: Thank you so much! Exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: Is there some way to order the selection? Like via fx:id or Text or Coordinates on the stage?

Comment: Of course: by manually sorting them. E.g. using java 8 streams api: `parent.getChildren().stream().filter(c -> c instanceof ToggleButton).map(c -> (ToggleButton)c).sorted(Comparator.comparingDouble(ToggleButton::layoutX)).forEach(...);`

Comment: Oh nice! Thanks again!

Comment: @AneeshCRao note that often the parent layout controls the positions making the sorting unnecessary in some cases.

Comment: If this answer helped, you need to accept it as the correct answer.